# ASP.NET Web Service not available, don't want WCF

Tags: c#, web-services

I want to create a really, really simple webservice in .Net/C# bottom up to generate my wsdl.

A simple tutorial
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/308359

is all I need, but in Visual Studio 2013 there is no such thing as 'ASP.NET Web Service' project. There are asp.net web applications which seem to exclude mentioning web services, and then there's WCF which seems far more complicated than what I really want and talks about supporting a multitude of protocols, data bindings, protocols, etc. I just want to write a few webmethods and go.

Thanks for any help :)

How do I do this? I really thought it would be a lot simpler than doing it in Java, but I'm stuck at the first hurdle.

Comment: Are you building a SOAP or REST service, or something else (eg. pure JSON service)?

Comment: While it's possible to generate and old .asmx style web service, these are deprecated, and will eventually go away.  Support will not last long for them.  If you want to generate wsdl, your only other choice is wcf.  ASP.NET WebAPI is the new hotness, but is RESTful and doesn't use WSDL.

Answer (score 2):

1. Create a web application project
2. Select 'Add New Item'

In the list, select Web Service. this will add a .asmx style web service which is what it sounds like you want.

Comment: thanks, they don't have make something so simple complicated ;)

well, what I mean is there's not much help on the internet for this, it's either old style which is not an option or WCF based which seems overly complicated when all you want is a basic web service.